# How do I .remove something that appears two times?

Tags: python-3.x

I some code that I have for an exercise I need to use the remove command (I don’t know if that thing is a command but I don’t know what it is.) The service I’m using want’s me to use the remove command to get rid of a piece of data in a 2d list I have. But I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):\
File "script.py", line 13, in ‹module\
customer_data. remove (False)\
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

I haven’t tried much since the service only want me to use remove and no loops to remove the data from the list.

```
first_names = ['Ainsley', 'Ben', 'Chani', 'Depak']

preferred_size = ['Small', 'Large', 'Medium']
preferred_size.append('Medium')

print(first_names)
print('')
print(preferred_size)
print('')

customer_data = [['Ainsley', 'Small', True],['Ben', 'Large', False],['Chani', 'Medium', True],['Depak', 'Medium', False]]

customer_data.remove(False)\
customer_data[2][2] = False
print(customer_data)
```

Comment: `remove` is a function/method.  And that error means there isn't a `False` at all in the list.

Comment: Thanks! Also there are two Falses in the code. I will add the code to my original question

Comment: There is only one `False` in each sub-list, and there are no `False`s in `customer_data`. You cannot use `remove` to remove elements of sub lists. You'd need to call `remove` directly on each list in `customer_list`.

Comment: Ok, how and I able to do that? Would it be something like: customer_data[1].remove(False)?

Comment: Typically with a loop, but if you can't use a loop, then ya, you'll need to use manual indexing.

Comment: If I was to use a loop how would I do that.

Comment: Iterate over `customer_data` with a `for` loop and use it to get each list for you. Then you can just call `remove` on the lists it gives you.